# something went wrong when login to heroku using eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, git, heroku, eclipse-plugin

I have a problem with 'Heroku' Eclipse plug-in.something went wrong when login to Heroku. I am on Ubuntu box; when i am trying to login using eclipse Heroku plug-in it show me a error something like this:

```
Unable to access Eclipse's secure ...verify your secure store settings.
```

i am using eclipse:

```
Eclipse Platform

Version: 3.7.2
Build id: I20110613-1736
With Aptana Plug-in
```

i have already googled the error but in-vain i can't find the relevant information regarding the issue.How can i resolve this issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If you come across this error then rename the .eclipse folder inside
>   your home to get it resolved. This issue happens when you switch
>   between a 32 bit and a 64 bit eclipse usually.

which is from http://shinusworkspace.blogspot.com.au/2012/12/unable-to-access-eclipses-secure-store.html

I was interchanging between using Springsource for grails (which is 32 bit) and the 64 bit JEE eclipse build for different projects.

Renaming the .eclipse folder causes it to be recreated on the next launch of eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with eclipse Juno v4.2
Try the following steps before you login to Heroku from Eclipse. It worked for me..

```
Go to Eclipse > window > Prefrences > Security > Secure Storage.
Click **Clear Passwords** button > Apply > OK.
```